# Export animation time into a file

Tags: python, animation, export

I have an animated points in my scene and I want to know how I can export the animation time? I've used batFINGER's answer found here [Script for save camera position, to file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58916/script-for-save-camera-position-to-file/58922#58922) to export the data that I want to add the time per frame, how I can add the time?

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58916/script-for-save-camera-position-to-file/58922#58922

Comment: Vertices or empties?

Comment: @poor my points are empties

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER, as batFINGER suggested I've done it using batFINGER's answer found here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58916/script-for-save-camera-position-to-file/58922#58922 except for adding the time, how I can add the time?

Comment: What I'd do: https://gist.github.com/p2or/b30ff4a9255283b2f33af21c97e4b064, based on `operator_file_export.py` template as batFINGER suggested in the other post. Usually it's not relevant adding the time in an ascii table, the importer should handle that.

Comment: The time in seconds is `frame / fps` where `fps = scene.render.fps  / scene.render.fps_base`